# Flexible number of for-loops - Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to use a flexible amount of for-loops or some solution that will do the same. Basically I want a variable to go from 0 to 100 in each loop and go through all combinations. The for-loops are nested so if I am looking for a solution for two agents I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++){
 for(int j = 0; j<=100, j++){
   //do some stuff with i and j
 }
}
```

but I do not ex ante know how many agents will be needed so I'm looking for a flexible way to get the same result. This might be quite an easy question but I was not able to find a threat which gave me a working solution.

EDIT: It was pointed out to me that the question is not clear enough, I will try to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

Let's say I have n agents, if n == 1 then I would need this:

```
for(int j = 0; j<=100, j++){
       //do some stuff with j
}
```

for n == 2 I would want:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j<=100, j++){
       //do some stuff with i and j
     }
    }
```

for n == 3 another for look around these existing ones and so on, but it need to be flexible as the user is asked for n and can type in any integer.
//EndEDIT I hope this made it clearer

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you plan to do with these nested for loops exactly. I am asking because creating an big number of nested for loops might not be the best approach

Comment: I am checking for solutions and finding Nash equilibria with a varying number of agents. This is the (easy) brute force approach but it won't be used with many agents anyways, so (I hope) that this will be a sufficient solution.

Comment: @NikNet the question is not clear

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is clear now, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is recursively.

Assuming you want the same limits on each range (i.e. that i,j,k etc go from 0..100), you can do it like so:

```
void recursive(List<Integer> values, int depth) {
  if (values.size() == depth) {
    // Do the thing you want to do with the values, i.e. the "innermost loop".
  } else {
    // This is intentionally Integer, so that remove removes that value, not the element at that index.
    for (Integer a = 0; a <= 100; ++a) {
      values.add(a);
      recursive(values, depth);
      values.remove(a);
    }
  }
}
```

While there are fewer than `depth` values in the list, this adds each value in the range into the list in turn, and recurses.

Once there are enough values in the list, then it does the "thing" you want to do. The list will contain `depth` values, and you can access an individual value using `values.get(i)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems like exactly what I was looking for, two questions remain: 1. Is "depth" the number of for loops? 2. How do I access the values correctly? Say in the n==2 case how would I access i and j?

Comment: And maybe 3. What values do I give for "values" when I first call the method?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It says in the answer. Choose your own convention as to whether `values.get(0)` or `values.get(depth-1)` is "i". 3. An empty mutable list, e.g. `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps and suits my problem exactly!